# How to add callback function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
function $(id) {
    if (id) {
        if (window === this) {
            return new $(id);
        }

        this.e = document.getElementById(id);
        return this;
    } else {
        return about;
    }
}

$.prototype = {
    click: function () {
        this.e.onclick = function () {
            alert("hi..");
        }
    }
};
```

when I excute this code :

```
$("skg").click2();
```

it return alert msg.

But I want to add a callback function like this :

```
$("skg").click(function(){
    alert("hi SKG");
});
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example 1**

```
$.prototype = {
    click: function (callback) {
        this.e.onclick = callback
    }
};
```

but if you want to parse the DOM element you can do something like this:

**Example 2**

```
$.prototype = {
    click: function (callback) {
        this.e.onclick = function() {
           callback.call(this); 
        }
    }
};
```

---

### EDIT:

Haha... Actually there is almost no difference.

But if you want to parse some custom arguments to your callback you can do it in the last example:

---

**your call:**

```
var handler = function(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...) {
    alert("Some alert");
};
$("someID").click(handler);
```

---

**Example 1:**

`handler` gets DOM element as `this` so:

`this = [HTML DOMElement]`

The first arguments in `handler` (called `arg1` (can also be accessed throw the array like variable `arguments` as the first `arguments[0]`)) contains the click's event property.

`arguments[0] = [Event Object]`

---

**Example 2:**

`this = [HTML DOMElement]`

Thats all. But you have the ability to parse extra arguments to the `hander`:

If your code is like this:

```
$.prototype = {
    click: function (callback) {
        this.e.onclick = function(event) {
           callback.call(this, event, {custom: "argument"} ); 
        }
    }
};
```

The handler will get:

`arguments[0] = [Event Object]` // Same as Example 1

But see now:

`arguments[1] = [Object object]`

or more precise:

`arguments[1] = {custom: "argument"}`

And as before you can access it throw `arg2` but also the array like `arguments[1]`.

---

**When i say array like i mean:**

It have some of the same abilities as an array:

The length property: `.length` (`arguments.length`).

The 0-index naming: `[n]` (`arguments[0]`, `arguments[1]`, ...)

But none of the native array methods like `sort`, `push`, `pop`, `splice`.

Even more but :) (And just a site note)

You can use array like objects in with native array method:

Lets say the arguments is like this: handler`("a", "b", "c", "d")`

and you only want the the 2th argument and higher:

`var args = [].splice.call(arguments, 0, 1)`

Now `args` is a native array with: `["b", "c", "d"]`.

Comment: Both work fine. Thanks
But what is the difference between the above two method.
Would you please explain it.

Answer (score 1):

look at function invocation via call/apply etc

```
function click( object, func ){

    // arguments[0] == object
    // arguments[1] == func

    var args = []; // empty array
    // copy all other arguments we want to "pass through" 
    for(var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++){
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    func.apply(object, args);
}
```

Comment: indeed, this addresses this issue in general (at a very low level), if he needs just an additional click listener/handler than other solutions here will do

Comment: you can make args like this: `var args = [].splice.call(arguments, 0, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Change that click function to take a method parameter and set the onclick event to that method:

```
click : function (callback){
           this.e.onclick = callback
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to your `click` function.

```
click: function (f) {
           this.e.onclick = f;
       }
```